# How to convert a list of dicts into bytes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

how can I convert a list of dicts into bytes so I can encode it and compress it after that.

```
obj = [{'State': ['California'], 'location': 'North', 'zipcode': '43567'}, 
       {'State': ['Texas'], 'location': 'Mid', 'zipcode': '43467'}]
base64.b64encode(zlib.compress(str.encode(obj, 'utf-8'), 6))
```

Getting this error,

```
TypeError: descriptor 'encode' requires a 'str' object but received a 'list'
```

Comment: Um, what sort of bytes? Any sort of serialization format? `str.encode` encoded a `str` object into a bytes object given a text encoding...

Comment: Consider the `pickle` (Python only) or `json` (generic) modules for serialization.

Comment: You need to be more specific. What should the bytes look like? What are you planning to do with the compressed, encoded result? Are you hoping to re-create the original list later, for example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should first use json to dumps the list of dicts:

```
import json
import base64
import zlib
obj = [{'State': ['California'], 'location': 'North', 'zipcode': '43567'}, {'State': ['Texas'], 'location': 'Mid', 'zipcode': '43467'}]
base64.b64encode(zlib.compress(str.encode(json.dumps(obj), 'utf-8'), 6))
```